# injecting JSON record to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get the artist name, among other fields, to be visible within the HTML page. As you can see from the code posted, the image is already showing on the page, so we don't quite understand where the issue lies.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById('searchform').addEventListener('submit', search);
})

//load V&A museum objects
function search(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var query = document.getElementById('query').value.trim();
  var url = "http://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?images=1&q=" + encodeURIComponent(query);

  console.log(url);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var i, item, img_id, img_url, img, artist,
        target = document.getElementById("result"),
        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(json);

      for (i = 0; i < json.records.length; i++) {
        item = json.records[i];
        console.log("artist = " + item.fields.artist);
        img_id = item.fields.primary_image_id;
        img_url = "http://media.vam.ac.uk/media/thira/collection_images/" +
          img_id.substr(0, 6) +
          "/" +
          img_id +
          "_jpg_o.jpg";

        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", img_url, );
        target.appendChild(img);

        artist = item.fields.artist;
        artist = document.createElement("h1");
        artist.setAttribute("h1", artist);
        artist = document.createElement("br");
        target.appendChild(artist);
      }
    }
  });
  xhr.open('GET', url, true); //true for asynchronous
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="va.css">
  <title>Victoria &amp; Albert Museum API TEST</title>
  <script src="va.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--<button id="button">Search</button>
    <br><br>
    <h1>Museum Objects</h1>
    <div id="objects"></div>-->

  <form id="searchform" class="form">
    <input type="text" id="query">
    <input type="submit" id="button">
  </form>

  <div id="result" class="objects">
    <!-- <div id="artists"><h1>Artists</h1></div> -->
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

The result is an image being pulled from the VA API, followed by the artist name. The image is visible but the artist only gets printed to the console.

Comment: You keep overwriting ``artist`` and the last thing in it is a break element.

Comment: In line with what the above comment says, you're probably looking for `artist +=` rather than `artist =`. Using `+=` adds to the variable rather than overwrites it.

Comment: I've tried changing the artist to the += recommendation and i'm still getting nothing. I don't understand why the 'complicated' image code will work, but not the basic text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the setting of attribute, along with the overwriting of artist as suggested.

```
artistName = item.fields.artist;
artist = document.createElement("h1");
var newContent = document.createTextNode(artistName);
artist.appendChild(newContent);
target.appendChild(artist);
```